Cannot find module '.prisma/client/default' when using prisma-extension-pagination
I cannot get prisma to work with this extension at all prisma-extension-pagination. It works fine with no extensions but when adding this one it starts with this error:
prop-1  | Error: Cannot find module '.prisma/client/default'
prop-1  | Require stack:
prop-1  | - /app/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@5.13.0_prisma@5.13.0/node_modules/@prisma/client/default.js
prop-1  | - /app/node_modules/.pnpm/prisma-extension-pagination@0.7.3_@prisma+client@5.13.0/node_modules/prisma-extension-pagination/dist/extension.js
prop-1  | - /app/node_modules/.pnpm/prisma-extension-pagination@0.7.3_@prisma+client@5.13.0/node_modules/prisma-extension-pagination/dist/index.js
prop-1  | - /app/dist/apps/prop/main.js
prop-1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
prop-1  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
prop-1  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
prop-1  |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
prop-1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@5.13.0_prisma@5.13.0/node_modules/@prisma/client/default.js:2:6)
prop-1  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
prop-1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
prop-1  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)

I'm using pnpm, any ideas please?

How do you configure the extension? Where is your $extends() statement?

i'm having your same error now after reinstalling prisma client

Happened to me just now, removing lock file and reinstalling dpeendency fixed the issue for me.

In your prisma schema:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../node_modules/.prisma/client"
}


make sure schema.prisma looks:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../node_modules/.prisma/client"
}

then run:
npx prisma generate
npx prisma db push
